# Side by side equations with only one equation number?

Tags: equations, numbering, align

I'm basically needing some help in coding this[image: this]
so that there is only one equation number. So far, I have produced this:

```
\begin{align}
 c_1(0) &= c_i, & c_1(L) &= c_e, \\
    c_2(0) &= c_i,      &    c_2(L) &= c_e, \\
    u(0) &= V,             &     u(L) &= 0.
\end{align}
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Add `\notag` to the first and third line in your `align` environment. It will remove the tag of those two line.

Comment: @AlainRemillard Thank-you!

Comment: Instead of `align`, use `equation` with `aligned` as a sub-environment.  (For displays with an even number of lines, this will center the equation number vertically.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As already suggested by @barbarabeeton, you could use an `aligned` environment inside an `equation` environment. An additional suggestion: To obtain a bit more horizontal separation between the two groups of three equations, insert `\qquad\qquad` right before the middle `&` alignment marker in the first row.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath} % for 'aligned' environment
\counterwithin{equation}{section} % optional
\usepackage{newtxtext,newtxmath}  % optional -- Times Roman text and math font

\begin{document}
\setcounter{section}{3} % just for this query
\setcounter{equation}{21}
\begin{equation}
\begin{aligned}
 c_1(0) &= c_i, \qquad\qquad&  c_1(L) &= c_e, \\
 c_2(0) &= c_i,             &  c_2(L) &= c_e, \\
\phi(0) &= V,               & \phi(L) &= 0.
\end{aligned}
\end{equation}
\end{document}
```

Comment: @AboAmmar - Many thanks for the edit!